# Authenticate different user types with Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to use two types of users: common user and admin. Now I already have an infrastructure where admins and users are two completely different types: users have many things related only to them(controllers, tables, services etc.), same for admins. Therefore, they are different entities and different tables in the DB, and I don't want to combine them, because they are different. But now only users can log in using Spring Security OAuth2, but admins not principals and they can't log in. Note that I use my own authorization and resource servers.

So, I want to allow Spring Security to authenticate both users and admins. I also want to use two different login endpoints and two different entities and tables for users and admins.

How can this be done or what should I do instead?

**UPD:**

I think I should create 2 OAuth clients with 2 different `grant_types` in `oauth_client_details` and 2 `AbstractTokenGranters` for users and for admins.

I already have a custom `AbstractTokenGranter` for users which authenticate users like this:

```
//getOAuth2Authentication()
User user = userService.getUserByPhone(username);

if(user == null)
    throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");

Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Long.toString(user.getId()), password)
);
//I use Long.toString(user.getId()) because some users use FB instead of the phone, 
//so I have one more `AbstractTokenGranter` for social networks, 
//I don't mention about it in this post, so don't be confused
```

As I understand, `AuthenticationManager` calls `UserDetailsService`, which looks like this now:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserDetails user = userRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(username)).orElseThrow(
                () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with id : " + id)
        );

        return user;
    }
```

But if I create one more `AbstractTokenGranter` for admins, then the current `UserDetailsService` will not know whose id it received - admin id or user id.

As a solution, I think I need to create one more `UserDetailsService` for admins. But how can I use multiple `UserDetailsService`? Also, maybe I should use a completely different scheme?

Comment: As I know you can define two authorization endpoint but isn't it better to load Grants to user who is admin or regular user. If you want to know how to define two different endpoint i can send you the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create new OAuth2 client in the `oauth_client_details` table with `custom_grant` in the `authorized_grant_types`.

2.Create:

```
public class CustomTokenGranter extends AbstractTokenGranter {

    //...

    protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(ClientDetails client, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {

        Map<String, String> params = tokenRequest.getRequestParameters();
        String username = params.getOrDefault("username", null);
        String password = params.getOrDefault("password", null);

        if(username == null || password == null)
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");

        CustomAuthenticationToken token = new CustomAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

    }
}
```

3.Add this granter in `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```
private TokenGranter tokenGranter(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    List<TokenGranter> granters = new ArrayList<TokenGranter>(Arrays.asList(endpoints.getTokenGranter()));
    granters.add(new CustomGrantTokenGranter(endpoints.getTokenServices(), endpoints.getClientDetailsService(), endpoints.getOAuth2RequestFactory(), "custom_grant"));
    return new CompositeTokenGranter(granters);
}
```

Now `CustomGrantTokenGranter` will receive all authorization request with `custom_grant` grant type.

4.Create `CustomAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

5.Create:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder adminPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService adminDetailsService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = auth.getName();
        String password = auth.getCredentials().toString();

        UserDetails adminDetails = adminDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        //adminDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username) returns Admin inside UserDetails

        if (adminPasswordEncoder.matches(password, adminDetails.getPassword()))
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(adminDetails, password, adminDetails.getAuthorities());
        else
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(CustomAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Here you can use `UserDetailsService` different from other providers

6.Add `CustomAuthenticationProvider` in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }
//...
}
```

**Summary:** with this scheme you can use as many user types as you want. If `Admin implements UserDetails`, then you can easily use it on the server as a `Principal`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<security:http pattern="/oauth/token" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless"
                   authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
                   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" method="GET" access="ROLE_DENY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" method="PUT" access="ROLE_DENY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" method="DELETE" access="ROLE_DENY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request
            parameters -->
        <security:custom-filter ref="contentTypeFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                                after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>


        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>
```

You can define custom clientDetailService and override loadUserByUserName method.
It is up to you whether you can query different tables and authorizations also you can change the structure. That is what i can say without more description

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        ClientDetails clientDetails;
        try {
            clientDetails = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(username);
        } catch (NoSuchClientException e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        String clientSecret = clientDetails.getClientSecret();
        if (clientSecret== null || clientSecret.trim().length()==0) {
            clientSecret = emptyPassword;
        }
        return new User(username, clientSecret, clientDetails.getAuthorities());
    }
```

This part can be modified to change structure :> authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"

If you are not using xml based, you can check annotation base link : 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I have some vision of how I can do it. Please check **UPD** section of my question

Comment: I think I found a solution, [you can check it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57422429/2656632). Feel free to comment